# Custom Open Activities Inline Vf page with sort functionality

Tags: apex, visualforce, activities, sort

As we [cannot sort open activities](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqX6AAK)  but on Go to List link page we can sort on any field  ( Go To link appears if there are more than 5 records..this is standard functionality) .so I've built a custom inline open activities visualforce page with the link to that page but page is not showing up properly(It shows as it appears on that link.I don't want header and sidebar and footer...  Just want records with sort functionality).

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="inlineOpenActivites" action="{!Taskslist}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

</apex:page>
```

---

```
    public  class inlineOpenActivites {
  public Id accountId {get;set;}
    public inlineOpenActivites(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       accountId =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    }

    public PageReference  Taskslist()
   {
      PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/007?id='+ accountId  +'&rlid=RelatedActivityList&closed=0L');
      return pageRef;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the **magic param : isdtp**

To know more on isdtp read http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html

Use **isdtp=lt** as a param in the url

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/007?id='+ accountId  +'&rlid=RelatedActivityList&closed=0L&isdtp=lt');
```

[image]

Comment: its working good in one org but in other org with custom domain the page is redirecting to above url (It should not redirect as it is inline VF Page)